# Legend that updates at the click of the mouse

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, legend

I created this sample heatmap: **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f0opWm5jTyrDW8WthGgo)**

Initially I use a certain linear scale `colorScale1` to color the heatmap.
When the user clicks on the legend, the color scale is updated and the threshold scale (`colorScale2`) is used.

This switch works well.

Now I don't know how to change the legend for the `colorScale2`.
The ticks and the gradient for `colorScale2` are wrong. I looked for a `linearGradient` equivalent for `scaleThreshold` but I didn't find anything.

This is the code:

```
var itemSize = 20;
var cellBorderSize = 1;
var cellSize = itemSize - 1 + cellBorderSize;

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10};
var width = 80 - margin.right - margin.left;
var height = 80 - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

var domain1 = [0, 80, 90, 95, 100];
var range1 = ['#EC93AB', '#CEB1DE', '#95D3F0', '#77EDD9', '#A9FCAA']; 
var colorScale1 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(domain1)
    .range(range1);

var domain2 = [0,   95, 100];
var range2 = ['white', 'lightgrey', 'grey']; 
var colorScale2 = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain(domain2)
    .range(range2);

svg.append('defs')
    .append('pattern')
        .attr('id', 'pattern-stripes')
        .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
        .attr('patternTransform', 'rotate(45)')
        .attr('width', 3)
        .attr('height', 3)
        .append('rect')
            .attr('width', 1)
            .attr('height', 3)
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')
            .attr('fill', 'black');

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Load data files.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var files = ['./data.csv'];
var promises = [];

promises.push(d3.csv(files[0]));

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(makeHeatmap)
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error loading files');
        throw err;
    });

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Data heatmap
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function makeHeatmap(myData) {
    var data = myData[0]; 

    // get each element of data file and creates an object
   var data = data.map(function(item) {
        var newItem = {};
        newItem.name = item.NAME;
        newItem.year = item.YEAR;
        newItem.val = item.VAL;
        return newItem;
    });

    var names = data.map(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });
    regionsName = d3.set(names).values();
    numRegions = regionsName.length; 

    var years = data.map(function(d) {
        return d.year;
    });
    yearsName = d3.set(years).values();
    numYears = yearsName.length; 

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Draw heatmap
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var cells = svg.selectAll('.cell')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .append('rect')
        .attr('data-value', function(d) { 
            return d.val; 
        })
        .attr('data-r', function(d) {
            var idr = regionsName.indexOf(d.name);
            return idr;             
        })
        .attr('data-c', function(d, i) {
            if(regionsName.includes(d.name) & d.year == '1990') var idc = 0;
            else if(regionsName.includes(d.name) && d.year == '1991') var idc = 1;
            else if(regionsName.includes(d.name) && d.year == '1992') var idc = 2;
            return idc; 
        })
        .attr('class', function() {
            var idr = d3.select(this).attr('data-r'); // row
            var idc = d3.select(this).attr('data-c'); // column
            return 'cell cr' + idr + ' cc' + idc;
        })
        .attr('width', cellSize)
        .attr('height', cellSize)
        .attr('x', function(d) { 
            var c = d3.select(this).attr('data-c');
            return c * cellSize;
        })
        .attr('y', function() { 
            var r = d3.select(this).attr('data-r');
            return r * cellSize;
        })
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
            var col;
            if(d.name == '') {
                col = 'url(#pattern-stripes)';
            }
            else {
                col = colorScale1(d.val); 
            }
            return col;
        });

} // end makeHeatmap

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Legend
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// create tick marks
var xLegend = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([10, 409]); // larghezza dei tick

var axisLegend = d3.axisBottom(xLegend)
    .tickSize(19) // height of ticks
    .tickFormat(function(v, i) { // i is index of domain colorScale, v is the corrisponding value (v = domain[i])
        if(v == 0) {
            return v + '%';
        }
        else {
            return v;
        }
    })
    .tickValues(colorScale1.domain());

var svgLegend = d3.select('#legend').append('svg').attr('width', 600);

// append title
svgLegend.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'legendTitle')
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', 20)
    .style('text-anchor', 'start')
    .text('Legend title');

// draw the rectangle and fill with gradient
svgLegend.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'legendRect')
    .attr('x', 10) // position
    .attr('y', 30)
    .attr('width', 400) // larghezza fascia colorata
    .attr('height', 15) // altezza fascia colorata
    .style('fill', 'url(#linear-gradient1)')
    .on('click', function() {
        if(currentFill === '1') {
            updateColor2();
            currentFill = '2';
        }
        else {
            updateColor1();
            currentFill = '1';
        }       
    });

svgLegend
    .attr('class', 'legendLinAxis')
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'legendLinG')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 30)') // 47 è la posizione verticale dei tick (se l'aumenti, scendono) (47 per farli partire sotto, 30 per farli partire da sopra)
    .call(axisLegend);

var defs = svgLegend.append('defs');

// horizontal gradient and append multiple color stops by using D3's data/enter step
var linearGradient1 = defs.append('linearGradient')
    .attr('id', 'linear-gradient1')
    .attr('x1', '0%').attr('y1', '0%')
    .attr('x2', '100%').attr('y2', '0%')
    .selectAll('stop')
    .data(colorScale1.domain())
    .enter().append('stop')
    .attr('offset', function(d) { 
        return d + '%'; 
    })
    .attr('stop-color', function(d) { 
        return colorScale1(d); 
    });

// horizontal gradient and append multiple color stops by using D3's data/enter step
var linearGradient2 = defs.append('linearGradient')
    .attr('id', 'linear-gradient2')
    .attr('x1', '0%').attr('y1', '0%')
    .attr('x2', '100%').attr('y2', '0%')
    .selectAll('stop')
    .data(colorScale2.domain())
    .enter().append('stop')
    .attr('offset', function(d) { 
        return d + '%'; 
    })
    .attr('stop-color', function(d) { 
        return colorScale2(d); 
    });

// update the colors to a different color scale (colorScale1)
function updateColor1() {
    // fill the legend rectangle
    svgLegend.select('.legendRect')
        .style('fill', 'url(#linear-gradient1)');
    // transition the cell colors
    svg.selectAll('.cell')
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .style('fill', function(d, i) { 
            var col;
            if(d.valuePol == '') {
                col = 'url(#pattern-stripes)';
            }
            else {
                col = colorScale1(d.val); 
            }
            return col;
        });
}

// update the colors to a different color scale (colorScale2)
function updateColor2() {
    // fill the legend rectangle
    svgLegend.select('.legendRect')
        .style('fill', 'url(#linear-gradient2)');
    // transition the cell colors
    svg.selectAll('.cell')
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .style('fill', function(d, i) { 
            var col;
            if(d.valuePol == '') {
                col = 'url(#pattern-stripes)';
            }
            else {
                col = colorScale2(d.val); 
            }
            return col;
        });
}

// start set-up
updateColor1();
var currentFill = '1';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code for which the legend's ticks and color scale are updated when clicking on the legend:

```js
var itemSize = 20;
var cellBorderSize = 1;
var cellSize = itemSize - 1 + cellBorderSize;

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10};
var width = 80 - margin.right - margin.left;
var height = 80 - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
 .append('svg')
 .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
 .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append('g')
 .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

var domain1 = [0, 80, 90, 95, 100];
var range1 = ['#EC93AB', '#CEB1DE', '#95D3F0', '#77EDD9', '#A9FCAA']; 
var colorScale1 = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain(domain1)
 .range(range1);

var domain2 = [0, 95, 100];
var range2 = ['white', 'lightgrey', 'grey']; 
var colorScale2 = d3.scaleThreshold()
 .domain(domain2)
 .range(range2);

svg.append('defs')
 .append('pattern')
  .attr('id', 'pattern-stripes')
  .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
  .attr('patternTransform', 'rotate(45)')
  .attr('width', 3)
  .attr('height', 3)
  .append('rect')
   .attr('width', 1)
   .attr('height', 3)
   .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')
   .attr('fill', 'black');

var data = [
  { "NAME": "ronnie", "YEAR": 1990, "VAL": 90 },
  { "NAME": "ronnie", "YEAR": 1991, "VAL": 95 },
  { "NAME": "ronnie", "YEAR": 1992, "VAL": 98 },
  { "NAME": "bob", "YEAR": 1990, "VAL": 92 },
  { "NAME": "bob", "YEAR": 1991, "VAL": 90 },
  { "NAME": "bob", "YEAR": 1992, "VAL": 99 },
  { "NAME": "carl", "YEAR": 1990, "VAL": 98 },
  { "NAME": "carl", "YEAR": 1991, "VAL": 99 },
  { "NAME": "carl", "YEAR": 1992, "VAL": 995 }
];

makeHeatmap(data);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Data heatmap
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function makeHeatmap(data) {
 //var data = myData[0]; 

 // get each element of data file and creates an object
   var data = data.map(function(item) {
  var newItem = {};
  newItem.name = item.NAME;
  newItem.year = item.YEAR;
  newItem.val = item.VAL;
  return newItem;
 });

 var names = data.map(function(d) {
  return d.name;
 });
 regionsName = d3.set(names).values();
 numRegions = regionsName.length; 

 var years = data.map(function(d) {
  return d.year;
 });
 yearsName = d3.set(years).values();
 numYears = yearsName.length; 

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Draw heatmap
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 var cells = svg.selectAll('.cell')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .append('rect')
  .attr('data-value', function(d) { 
   return d.val; 
  })
  .attr('data-r', function(d) {
   var idr = regionsName.indexOf(d.name);
   return idr;    
  })
  .attr('data-c', function(d, i) {
   if(regionsName.includes(d.name) & d.year == '1990') var idc = 0;
   else if(regionsName.includes(d.name) && d.year == '1991') var idc = 1;
   else if(regionsName.includes(d.name) && d.year == '1992') var idc = 2;
   return idc; 
  })
  .attr('class', function() {
   var idr = d3.select(this).attr('data-r'); // row
   var idc = d3.select(this).attr('data-c'); // column
   return 'cell cr' + idr + ' cc' + idc;
  })
  .attr('width', cellSize)
  .attr('height', cellSize)
  .attr('x', function(d) { 
   var c = d3.select(this).attr('data-c');
   return c * cellSize;
  })
  .attr('y', function() { 
   var r = d3.select(this).attr('data-r');
   return r * cellSize;
  })
  .attr('fill', function(d) {
   var col;
   if(d.name == '') {
    col = 'url(#pattern-stripes)';
   }
   else {
    col = colorScale1(d.val); 
   }
   return col;
  });

} // end makeHeatmap

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Legend
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// create tick marks
var xLegend = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, 100])
 .range([10, 409]); // larghezza dei tick

var axisLegend = d3.axisBottom(xLegend)
 .tickSize(19) // height of ticks
 .tickFormat(function(v, i) { // i is index of domain colorScale, v is the corrisponding value (v = domain[i])
  if(v == 0) {
   return v + '%';
  }
  else {
   return v;
  }
 });

var svgLegend = d3.select('#legend').append('svg').attr('width', 600);

// append title
svgLegend.append('text')
 .attr('class', 'legendTitle')
 .attr('x', 10)
 .attr('y', 20)
 .style('text-anchor', 'start')
 .text('Legend title');

// draw the rectangle and fill with gradient
svgLegend.append('rect')
 .attr('class', 'legendRect')
 .attr('x', 10) // position
 .attr('y', 30)
 .attr('width', 400) // larghezza fascia colorata
 .attr('height', 15) // altezza fascia colorata
 .style('fill', 'url(#linear-gradient1)')
 .on('click', function() {
  if(currentFill === '1') {
   updateColor2();
   currentFill = '2';
  }
  else {
   updateColor1();
   currentFill = '1';
  }  
 });

var legend = svgLegend
 .attr('class', 'legendLinAxis')
 .append('g')
 .attr('class', 'legendLinG')
 .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 30)'); // 47 è la posizione verticale dei tick (se l'aumenti, scendono) (47 per farli partire sotto, 30 per farli partire da sopra)

var defs = svgLegend.append('defs');

// horizontal gradient and append multiple color stops by using D3's data/enter step
var linearGradient1 = defs.append('linearGradient')
 .attr('id', 'linear-gradient1')
 .attr('x1', '0%').attr('y1', '0%')
 .attr('x2', '100%').attr('y2', '0%')
 .selectAll('stop')
 .data(colorScale1.domain())
 .enter().append('stop')
 .attr('offset', function(d) { 
  return d + '%'; 
 })
 .attr('stop-color', function(d) { 
  return colorScale1(d); 
 });

// horizontal gradient and append multiple color stops by using D3's data/enter step

function getGradient2data() {
  // Duplicates elements of domain2:
  var duplicatedDomain = domain2.reduce(function (res, current, index, array) { return res.concat([current, current]); }, []).slice(1, -1);
  // Duplicates elements of range2:
  var duplicatedRange = range2.slice(1).reduce(function (res, current, index, array) { return res.concat([current, current]); }, []);
  // Zips both domain and range:
  return duplicatedDomain.map( function(e, i) { return { "offset": e + "%", "color": duplicatedRange[i] }; [e, duplicatedRange[i]]; });
}

var linearGradient2 = defs.append('linearGradient')
 .attr('id', 'linear-gradient2')
 .attr('x1', '0%').attr('y1', '0%')
 .attr('x2', '100%').attr('y2', '0%')
 .selectAll('stop')
  .data(getGradient2data())
 //.data([                             
  //  { offset: "0%", color: "lightgrey" },
  //  { offset: "95%", color: "lightgrey" },
  //  { offset: "95%", color: "grey" },
  //  { offset: "100%", color: "grey" }
  //])
 .enter().append('stop')
 .attr('offset', function(d) { 
  return d.offset; 
 })
 .attr('stop-color', function(d) { 
  return d.color; 
 });

// update the colors to a different color scale (colorScale1)
function updateColor1() {
 // fill the legend rectangle
 svgLegend.select('.legendRect')
  .style('fill', 'url(#linear-gradient1)');
 // transition the cell colors
 svg.selectAll('.cell')
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .style('fill', function(d, i) { 
   var col;
   if(d.valuePol == '') {
    col = 'url(#pattern-stripes)';
   }
   else {
    col = colorScale1(d.val); 
   }
   return col;
  });
  
 axisLegend.tickValues(colorScale1.domain());
 legend.call(axisLegend);
}

// update the colors to a different color scale (colorScale2)
function updateColor2() {
 // fill the legend rectangle
 svgLegend.select('.legendRect')
  .style('fill', 'url(#linear-gradient2)');
 // transition the cell colors
 svg.selectAll('.cell')
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .style('fill', function(d, i) { 
   var col;
   if(d.valuePol == '') {
    col = 'url(#pattern-stripes)';
   }
   else {
    col = colorScale2(d.val); 
   }
   return col;
  });
  
 axisLegend.tickValues(colorScale2.domain());
 legend.call(axisLegend);
}

// start set-up
updateColor1();
var currentFill = '1';
```

```css
#heatmap {
 float: left;
 background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.cell {
 stroke: #E6E6E6;
 stroke-width: 1px;
}

/**
 * Legend linear.
 */
.legendTitle {
 font-size: 15px;
 fill: black;
 font-weight: 12;
 font-family: Consolas, courier;
}

#legendLin {
 background-color: yellow;
}

.legendLinAxis path, .legendLinAxis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: none;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.legendLinAxis text {
 font-family: Consolas, courier;
 font-size: 8pt;
 fill: black;
}

.legendLinG .tick line {
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
   <div id='heatmap'></div>
   <div id='legend'></div>
   <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Ticks update**:

Within the update functions (`updateColor1`, `updateColor2`), in addition to the update of the color scale gradient, we can also include the update of legend ticks (similar to how it was first initialized):

```
axisLegend.tickValues(colorScale1.domain());
legend.call(axisLegend);
```

---

**Gradient update**:

The creation of ["abrupt gradients"](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/b1fbcc0ff00abe8893a087d85fc8005b) is slightly different from the one of "linear gradients". Here is a slightly modified version of your `linear-gradient2` threshold gradient:

```
var linearGradient2 = defs.append('linearGradient')
  .attr('id', 'linear-gradient2')
  .attr('x1', '0%').attr('y1', '0%')
  .attr('x2', '100%').attr('y2', '0%')
  .selectAll('stop')
  .data([                             
    { offset: "0%", color: "lightgrey" },
    { offset: "95%", color: "lightgrey" },
    { offset: "95%", color: "grey" },
    { offset: "100%", color: "grey" }
  ])
  .enter().append('stop')
  .attr('offset', function(d) { return d.offset; })
.attr('stop-color', function(d) { return d.color; });
```

---

Or if the threshold gradient is to change, instead of hardcoding it, we can also get it from the defined domain and range:

```
function getGradient2data() {
  // Duplicates elements of domain2:
  var duplicatedDomain = domain2.reduce(function (res, current, index, array) { return res.concat([current, current]); }, []).slice(1, -1);
  // Duplicates elements of range2:
  var duplicatedRange = range2.slice(1).reduce(function (res, current, index, array) { return res.concat([current, current]); }, []);
  // Zips both domain and range:
  return duplicatedDomain.map( function(e, i) { return { "offset": e + "%", "color": duplicatedRange[i] }; [e, duplicatedRange[i]]; });
}
```

which produces:

```
[                             
  { offset: "0%", color: "lightgrey" },
  { offset: "95%", color: "lightgrey" },
  { offset: "95%", color: "grey" },
  { offset: "100%", color: "grey" }
]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply!
It works perfectly but I have a question: why can I not use `.data(colorScale2.domain())` for create the threshold gradient?
Is there an automatic procedure to get offset and color instead of using `[{offset: "0%", color: "lightgrey"}, {offset: "95%", color: "lightgrey"},{offset: "95%", color: "grey"}, {offset: "100%", color: "grey"}]`?
I ask you because if I change the `domain2` or the `range2` in `colorScale2`, I should also manually change `[{offset: "0%", color: "lightgrey"}, {offset: "95%", color: "lightgrey"},{offset: "95%", color: "grey"}, ...]`.
Thank you

Comment: @ColdFish Sorry for the delay; updated the answer to avoid hardcoding the stops for the second gradient.